# "on each side" vs "on all the sides"

Tags: phrase-meaning

(1a) The box has a different pattern **on each side.**

(1b) The box has a different pattern **on all the sides.**

Do both sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: I would never say option 1b. I would say "on all sides".

Answer (score 0):

> The box has a different pattern on each side.

OR

> The box has a different pattern on every side.

OR

> The box has a different pattern on all sides

Answer (score 0):

For brevity, I would go with 1a. For clarity, I would state something like:

- Each side of the box has a different pattern.
- The box has six sides and each side has a unique pattern.
- There are six unique patterns for each side of the box.
- A distinctly unique pattern adorns each side of the box.

Sorry, the last three are more descriptive, and verbose.